# Section with multi-column text

Tags: tables, multicol

I want to create a section in which the text appears in three columns, its similar to a table with three columns and one row, but without any outlines, and multi-line text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) out of convenience since it provides an easy-to-use `X`-column. The reduction of `25pt` is to avoid an overfull `\hbox` from being set; since it's a heading, it didn't seem to require such precision.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\section[Absurd section heading]
  {\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-25pt}[t]{@{}XXX@{}}
    \raggedright Some very long text in the far left column & 
    \centering Some very long text in the centre column & 
    \raggedleft Some very long text in the far right column
   \end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the optional parameter for the sectional unit. This may be necessary if you are using a `\tableofcontents`.